# hive error, getting an EOF error in subtract query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am getting an, missing EOF at '-' near HAB, the query for the most part looks correct. just not sure how to implement minus in HIVE.

```
SELECT
    a.playerID AS ID,
    a.yearID AS yearID,
    (b.HAB - a.EG) AS HAB-EG
FROM 
    (SELECT
        playerID,
        yearID,
        (E/G) AS EG
    FROM fielding
    WHERE (
            yearID > 2005
            AND yearID < 2009
            AND G > 20 
            )
    ) AS a
JOIN
    (SELECT
        id,
        year,
        (hits/ab) AS HAB
    FROM batting
    WHERE( 
            year > 2005
            AND year < 2009 
            AND ab > 40 
            )
    ) AS b ON a.playerID = b.id AND a.yearID = b.year;
```

Comment: The problem is with using `HAB-EG` as a column alias, put it inside a backticks i.e. `\`HAB-EG\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias names should be quoted with ``` backtick character (``) ``` characters, when you include any additional character such as space or dash.
So use following:

```
SELECT
    a.playerID AS ID,
    a.yearID AS yearID,
    (b.HAB - a.EG) AS `HAB-EG`
```

Comment: ohh yeah.. didn't notice that.. :(